# php ioc container within plugin

Tags: php, plugins, inversion-of-control, ioc-container

I am writing a plugin for a content management system that does not use a ioc container.

Is is good practise to use my own ioc container like Pimple within my plugin to manage all my classes etc even though the framework my plugin extends does not use one?

Answer (score 0):

I realize it's an old question but here it goes:

It's always a good practice to use IoC. It helps you separate object creation and using them.

The question is more like: can you?
The IoC container has to know about all the shared dependency instances you need from the CMS (otherwise it will create new ones), so you will need to list all of them, before you can request creating your own objects. This might create a problem.

Imagine, you have a common use case scenario where you use a single shared dependency from that CMS. You also have a rare case, where you use 10 other shared dependencies, all from and instantiated by the CMS. For this injection to work, you will need to add all 11 dependency instances to the IoC, even though, you will need a single one most of the time, and probably the other 10 never would have been instantiated (but now they are, because you needed instances to them). You also should not add the same logic to dependency providing that you have on instance selection, because you are duplicating code, and it's also the job you want to delegate to the IoC.

In conclusion, if your plugin heavily depends on singleton services from the CMS (note: not singleton patterns, but shared instances) then you can't really do it efficiently. If you can access all these from public scope (singleton pattern), you might be able to do it, but then your plugin won't be testable, and you also kill the purpose of the IoC.

If you are allowed to create your own dependencies from the CMS, or you don't really depend on it, or you always use every dependency you need, you are good to go, but these are all rare use cases.